# Insert empty value JTextFormatted to double column to mysql

Tags: java, mysql, isnullorempty

I have a jtextformattedfield where i insert a double number that i save in double column of table mysql. Sometimes jtextformattedfield is empty and show error because don't accept null value.

```
Double n = ((Number)numero.getValue()).doubleValue();
pst.setDouble(2,n);
```

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities:

1. You change your MySql table so that the columns can accept NULL, but I guess they are keys and you cannot make that change
2. You make an if in your code and do not update on empty value.

Regards